# How can I train s neuronal network in r using AMORE

Tags: r, neural-network, rstudio, training-data

I'm trying to train a neural network (NN) in RStudio using "AMORE", but my dataset has non numeric attributes.

I use this:

```
library("AMORE", lib.loc="/usr/lib/R/site-library")
redNeuronal<-newff(n.neurons=c(6,8,7,2), learning.rate.global=1, momentum.global=0.5, error.criterium="LMS", Stao=NA, hidden.layer="tansig", output.layer="purelin", method="ADAPTgdwm")
train(redNeuronal, experimentacion, experimentacion$Expected, Pval=NULL, Tval=NULL, error.criterium="LMS", report=TRUE, TRUE, 50, Stao=NA,prob=NULL)
```

Where `experimentacion` is my dataset with 20 variables and `Expected` is the variable I want to predict from the other 19 (my test dataset has only the other 19 variables and has to be able to predict `Expected`)

This is the error it throws:

```
Error in train.method(net, P, T, show.step) : 
   REAL() can only be applied to a 'numeric', not a 'character'
```

Why does this error occur?

Comment: Probably `experimentacion` is not what you think it is. You can use `class()` and `str()` to check what it really is.

Comment: experimentacion is a dataset I downloaded from `http://www.kaggle.com/`

Comment: Which competition/dataset is it?

Comment: `https://www.kaggle.com/c/how-much-did-it-rain`